# Sort subdirectories in a directory in a for loop

Tags: bash, scripting, command

Supposing you have

```
for subdir in *
```

and you want the subdirectories (named 1, 2, ..., 10, 11...) in the parent one be read in human numerical order, i.e. 1, 2, 3 etc and not in the machine one, i.e. 1, 10 etc. How do you perform it?

Comment: See [BashFAQ/003](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/003) for a robust way to do this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `-n` (`--numeric-sort`) option to [`sort`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/sort) to sort in numeric order:

```
~/tmp for f in $(ls | sort -n); do echo $f; done
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
10

~/tmp for f in $(ls); do echo $f; done
1
10
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

If you don't need to do any operation, you simply want to list the directories in order:

```
ls | sort -n
```

Comment: I thought about the sort -n too, indeed I tested it with ls obtaining the expected result, but I didn't know how to use it in the for' arguments. Thank you very much!